# Using ReadFile function to read data from a process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to read data from a process using the Win32 API function `ReadFile()`.  I am not using the standard library function because I'm using a source code from a public repo.  Here I provide the specific snippet I have trouble with..

```
//Those are Globals
HANDLE pipin_w, pipin_r, pipout_w, pipout_r;
DWORD write, read, available;
BYTE buffer[2048];

std::string myFunction(){
    std::string out="";
    PeekNamedPipe ( pipout_r, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, &available, NULL);
    sleep(300);
    do {
        ZeroMemory(*buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        ReadFile( pipout_r, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, NULL);

        if (!read) { return std::string("error"); }
        buffer[read]=0;
        out += (char*)buffer;
    } while(read >= sizeof(buffer));
    return out;
}
```

The first two calls respond correctly, than `"error"` gets returned.

I wasn't able to use and understand the standard library function because I have no experience in C++ programming.  What I'm trying to do is to fill the `BYTE` buffer that has size 2048.

This code works for the first two calls, then the `read` variable gets corrupted. I know that my initialization is correct because I am able to connect with the process which opens itself in the Task Manager, and also I am able to retrieve data from it, but after a pair of calls the `read` variable gets corrupted.

That causes hangs or crashes in my code. There are a few things which I don't like about this code. For example, I was not able to use the standard library functions like `fstream`, so I have decided to stick with this setting for now.  Also, I don't know if it is correct to read from the process with the `ReadFile()` function, but that sort of works.  And the `while` loop feels quiet uncomfortable for me, I can't understand why I need it.

Anyone who wants to know how I have initialized this code, feel free to ask, I will provide every missing info, but I don't think that is an issue because I am able to make a couple of readings from the process itself.  I can provide a link to the source code that I am using since that's a public source code repository.

Maybe Asked Questions (from you):

1. Does your process support reading?

   Yes It does
2. Do you have enough permissions to run and read the process?

   Yes I have
3. Maybe you need to write some data to tell the process to start the communication..

   That's not the case, I have another function to write data, and I use it before this call, but I still receive data even if I don't write to it
4. How do you create your process?

   I can provide that snippet, just ask me, but essentialy I create two pipes, one for Reading and another for writing, then I start the process by calling CreateProcess, and that works.
5. What are you trying to do with your code?

   I am trying to build a class which can handle the creation, the writing, and the reading of a process in a Windows platform environment with c++, nothing more..

What can possibly cause the corruption of the `read` variable?  I am struggling to understand that, and how I can avoid it.  Also, if someone can explain to me good practices for this kind of situations, I really appreciate that, or at least to have a link to some resources I can look at, or to study how that works.

Comment: You might want to call `GetLastError()` more often.

Comment: How is [tag:w32] different from [tag:winapi]?

Answer (score 1):

- `ZeroMemory(*buffer, sizeof(buffer));` should be `ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));`
  In it's current state, you read the first `BYTE` in `buffer` and use that as the address to start zeroing at. This causes undefined behavior.
- `buffer[read]=0;` is potentially writing out of bounds. If you've read `2048` `BYTE`s, you have undefined behavior.
- `out += (char*)buffer;` reads `buffer` until it finds `\0` - but there's no need for that since you already know how many `BYTE`s you've read.

Fixes:

- Remove `ZeroMemory` - you will only read memory that's been filled by `ReadFile` so it's just a waste of time to zero it out first.
- Replace

  ```
  buffer[read]=0;
  out += (char*)buffer;
  ```

  with

  ```
  out.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), read);
  ```

Also, check the return value of the functions you call. `ReadFile` may fail for example.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! i wasn't able sto static_cast<char*> cause compiler says "invalid conversion type", so made it like this: out.append((char*)buffer); but i have removed the ZeroMemory call, and buffer[read]=0. also, ive put GetLastError() directly after PeekNamedPipe and ReadFile, but it always return 0, anyway the read variable keeps getting corrupted

Comment: My mistake. I fixed the casting in the answer. `out.append((char*)buffer)` is not right though. You need `out.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), read);` Btw, why do you do `PeekNamedPipe`?

Comment: this is how i create the two pipe
CreatePipe(&pipout_r, &pipout_w, &sats, 0);
CreatePipe(&pipin_r, &pipin_w, &sats, 0);
and this is how i peek the out pipe PeekNamedPipe(pipout_r, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, &available, NULL); also those are the STARTUPINFO sti for how i create the process sti.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
sti.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
sti.hStdInput = pipin_r;
sti.hStdOutput = pipout_w;
sti.hStdError = pipout_w;

Comment: I see how you `PeekNamedPipe` but I don't see that you do anything with the result so I wonder why you do it?

Comment: It was in the orginal source code, i did not remove it. with renterpreted_cast gives me access violation at address, and crashes even the first time i call it :( . You say that is better to just call it once, after creating the process, or not calling it at all?

Comment: Your `(char*)` does the same thing, so that's not it. It's because `read` probably contained something bad. I'm looking at `PeekNamedPipe` in your question. I don't see how you use the result? Try this: `if (ReadFile(pipout_r, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &read, nullptr) == TRUE) {
            out.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), read);
        }`

Comment: ok, i have tried that, seems that something is still misssing.. i still get crashes

Comment: @MarioVincifranchi That's ok. When you solve it, you can do a write-up as an answer to your question. It may help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The crashes all gone, after i reverted the casting to a char pointer, i did not understand quite well cast conversion, but since i allocated memory by first initializing the char pointer to nullptr, then i used memset to allocate a bigger buffer, somehow my approce works with this kind of situation, as i do not use it anywhere else in my code, if i need it, i just copy it to a new initialized string using std::string, so that solved the continous crash problem, and onestly i cant figure out a better approch to this.

Next, what i premused was also a crash, it was really an infinite loop by the ReadFile function, and it occures in two kind of situation.

1. when i pass a "wrong" string to communicate with it, some kind of special caharcters (such as \ or /)
2. When the buffer has nothing to read from the application, and the application returns empty output

Still not sure how to handle the second case :( but at least i can continue debugging... :)